# Optimum display resolution can't be achieved with Intel HD 4000 graphics card

Tags: resolution, intel-graphics, intel-core-i7, display-settings

Every distro I use does not recognise the **Intel HD 4000** internal graphics card, which is not recognized, and I am unable to set my monitor optimum resolution.

I have tried `xrandr`, but that's not a permanent solution, and even this does not fit the whole screen. I've even tried updating kernels, which generally result in a blackout, where after `grub`, I am only able to see a black screen.

I tried different distros like Mint, OpenSuse, Ubuntu, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution  through xrandr but I copied the modline from https://arachnoid.com/modelines/ when you add mode through this these solves the issue